# Override the django save and update function. both are working fine but for update function it is entering in a infinite loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, overriding

**Override the django save and update function. both are working fine but for update function it is entering in a infinite loop**

```
class PrimitiveQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().update(*args, **kwargs)
        super().using('New').update(*args, **kwargs)


class Primitive(models.Model):
    
    modified_by = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    modified_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    deleted_by = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    deleted_on = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    deleted_flag = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True, default=False)

    objects = PrimitiveQuerySet.as_manager()
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Dump data into default database
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        # Save the same data to the new database
        using_db = kwargs.pop('using', None)  # Extract 'using' parameter
        self._state.db = using_db  # Set the target database for saving
        self.save_base(using='New', force_insert=False, force_update=False
`
```

I got the approach how to update and save data in two db but issue is it is going into infinite loop

Comment: The `.using('New')` creates a `PrimiteQuerySet` that will then thus call `.update` and thus get stuck in an infinite loop...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.